# How to fill a drop-down list with the names of the columns in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

I work from a table with 3 columns and I want to fill a drop-down list with the names of the columns. I wrote this code but it doesn't work. I only have the name of the first column

```
ActiveSheet.DropDowns("Zone combinée 3").ListFillRange = Application.Transpose("'Opoci'!$A$1:$C$1")
```

Could you, please, help me ?

Regards

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: _" I only have the name of the first column"_ -> I guess your issue is that you want to fill the DD from values in a row: Well, you can't and you must point to a single column range address (like `...ListFillRange = "'Opoci'!$A$1:$A$3"` . So either you change the data layout in sheet "Opoci" (!) or use a "helper" one-columned range as the transpose of the one-rowed range and set `ListFillRange` to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ControlFormat.ListFillRange property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.controlformat.listfillrange) only accepts a string of an address like

```
.ListFillRange = "A1:A10"
```

Comment: @PEH, Thank you for this information. I was able to adapt my code accordingly